# How to calulate KL-Divergence using kernel densities in Python?

Tags: python, kernel-density, probability-distribution

I have a set of (100, 3) Jaccarad-Index values, where the '3' denotes the number of model-input parameters. I want to compute the KL-Divergence for each combination of features using the sampling distribution of Jaccard indices. I'm truly at a loss on how to compute (numerically) probability distributions (or specifically kernel densities) for each column of Jaccard Index values with the hope of computing the KL-Divergence. At this point, I feel as if I don't know what I'm doing or, at least, there's a gap in understanding (wherever it may be). If someone can 'shepherd' me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it. Below, I provided the array of Jaccard Index values. I apologize if this isn't the correct format for displaying a dataset this large (idk any other way), but I really need help.

```
np.array([[0.12    , 1.      , 0.272727],
       [0.074074, 0.882353, 0.208333],
       [0.16    , 0.933333, 0.25    ],
       [0.192308, 0.888889, 0.148148],
       [0.238095, 0.473684, 0.45    ],
       [0.26087 , 0.933333, 0.26087 ],
       [0.333333, 0.75    , 0.3     ],
       [0.2     , 0.722222, 0.166667],
       [0.318182, 0.823529, 0.25    ],
       [0.076923, 0.631579, 0.217391],
       [0.142857, 0.722222, 0.26087 ],
       [0.115385, 0.555556, 0.125   ],
       [0.136364, 0.875   , 0.3     ],
       [0.166667, 0.722222, 0.318182],
       [0.115385, 0.764706, 0.166667],
       [0.166667, 1.      , 0.130435],
       [0.125   , 1.      , 0.08    ],
       [0.272727, 0.666667, 0.181818],
       [0.222222, 0.571429, 0.142857],
       [0.26087 , 0.5     , 0.304348],
       [0.076923, 1.      , 0.333333],
       [0.470588, 0.8     , 0.25    ],
       [0.125   , 0.611111, 0.285714],
       [0.083333, 0.625   , 0.2     ],
       [0.26087 , 0.866667, 0.16    ],
       [0.181818, 0.555556, 0.25    ],
       [0.304348, 0.9375  , 0.318182],
       [0.166667, 0.928571, 0.388889],
       [0.192308, 0.684211, 0.304348],
       [0.26087 , 0.866667, 0.190476],
       [0.2     , 0.555556, 0.3     ],
       [0.076923, 0.705882, 0.16    ],
       [0.115385, 1.      , 0.444444],
       [0.208333, 0.611111, 0.2     ],
       [0.2     , 0.833333, 0.333333],
       [0.125   , 0.555556, 0.333333],
       [0.166667, 0.681818, 0.103448],
       [0.166667, 1.      , 0.166667],
       [0.173913, 0.764706, 0.153846],
       [0.208333, 0.6     , 0.16    ],
       [0.2     , 0.444444, 0.2     ],
       [0.153846, 0.736842, 0.166667],
       [0.074074, 0.777778, 0.4     ],
       [0.071429, 0.9375  , 0.16    ],
       [0.153846, 0.705882, 0.173913],
       [0.111111, 1.      , 0.130435],
       [0.142857, 0.789474, 0.148148],
       [0.166667, 0.722222, 0.148148],
       [0.142857, 0.888889, 0.16    ],
       [0.285714, 0.526316, 0.125   ],
       [0.103448, 0.6     , 0.107143],
       [0.148148, 0.777778, 0.192308],
       [0.137931, 0.714286, 0.2     ],
       [0.181818, 0.8125  , 0.285714],
       [0.136364, 0.388889, 0.125   ],
       [0.227273, 0.588235, 0.25    ],
       [0.136364, 0.625   , 0.238095],
       [0.157895, 0.5625  , 0.095238],
       [0.3     , 0.473684, 0.181818],
       [0.130435, 1.      , 0.285714],
       [0.318182, 0.75    , 0.388889],
       [0.24    , 0.6     , 0.26087 ],
       [0.173913, 0.55    , 0.26087 ],
       [0.173913, 0.684211, 0.217391],
       [0.111111, 1.      , 0.208333],
       [0.115385, 0.684211, 0.2     ],
       [0.227273, 0.8125  , 0.368421],
       [0.227273, 1.      , 0.130435],
       [0.24    , 0.7     , 0.192308],
       [0.173913, 0.764706, 0.272727],
       [0.304348, 0.8125  , 0.333333],
       [0.291667, 0.666667, 0.347826],
       [0.107143, 0.6     , 0.208333],
       [0.192308, 0.842105, 0.2     ],
       [0.217391, 0.714286, 0.12    ],
       [0.217391, 1.      , 0.076923],
       [0.190476, 0.764706, 0.208333],
       [0.033333, 0.571429, 0.153846],
       [0.208333, 0.941176, 0.272727],
       [0.333333, 0.722222, 0.153846],
       [0.153846, 0.823529, 0.217391],
       [0.136364, 0.8     , 0.529412],
       [0.1     , 0.714286, 0.185185],
       [0.142857, 0.785714, 0.333333],
       [0.173913, 0.526316, 0.25    ],
       [0.208333, 0.388889, 0.25    ],
       [0.16    , 0.6     , 0.16    ],
       [0.272727, 0.764706, 0.238095],
       [0.086957, 0.625   , 0.190476],
       [0.103448, 0.684211, 0.24    ],
       [0.238095, 0.444444, 0.173913],
       [0.35    , 0.875   , 0.227273],
       [0.12    , 0.823529, 0.238095],
       [0.28    , 0.722222, 0.178571],
       [0.208333, 0.944444, 0.185185],
       [0.2     , 0.611111, 0.208333],
       [0.095238, 0.473684, 0.12    ],
       [0.190476, 0.733333, 0.210526],
       [0.192308, 0.75    , 0.217391],
       [0.12    , 0.764706, 0.217391]])
```

I have used Seaborn's 'displot' (with "kind='kde'") to return plots for each column of Jaccard Index values: [KDE for features 0, 1, and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlz0R.png). I have also used scipy.gaussian_kde, with the hope that it'll return probabilities but to no avail (of course), and I've tried plt.hist from matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: Do you really need to use KDE?  How about non-parametric estimators?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Sorry for the late reply.  I'm personally unfamiliar with those method at the moment.

Comment: I mean computing KL from samples, a la https://github.com/gregversteeg/NPEET or https://github.com/BiuBiuBiLL/NPEET_LNC

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Is this like bootstraping? I’m familiar with that. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to get you started I've extracted some code from NPEET library, and it produced something reasonable for one case (though other cases gave me log(0) exception), **z** is your samples array

Python 3.10, Windows 10 x64

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, KDTree

L = 100

a = z[:,0].reshape((L,1))
b = z[:,1].reshape((L,1))
c = z[:,2].reshape((L,1))

def query_neighbors(tree, x, k):
    return tree.query(x, k = k + 1)[0][:, k]

def build_tree(points):
    if points.shape[1] >= 20:
        return BallTree(points, metric="chebyshev")
    return KDTree(points, metric="chebyshev")

def kldiv(x, xp, k=3, base=2):
    """KL Divergence between p and q for x~p(x), xp~q(x)
    x, xp should be a list of vectors, e.g. x = [[1.3], [3.7], [5.1], [2.4]]
    if x is a one-dimensional scalar and we have four samples
    """
    assert k < min(len(x), len(xp)), "Set k smaller than num. samples - 1"
    assert len(x[0]) == len(xp[0]), "Two distributions must have same dim."
    x, xp = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(xp)
    x, xp = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1), xp.reshape(xp.shape[0], -1)
    d = len(x[0])
    n = len(x)
    m = len(xp)
    const = np.log(m) - np.log(n - 1)
    tree = build_tree(x)
    treep = build_tree(xp)
    nn = query_neighbors(tree, x, k)
    nnp = query_neighbors(treep, x, k - 1)
    kld = (const + d * (np.log(nnp).mean() - np.log(nn).mean())) / np.log(base)
    return kld

ab_kldiv = kldiv(a,b, 6, 2)
print(ab_kldiv)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, truly! To give you some background, I’m working on my thesis at the moment, which is in the area of UQ (specifically SA). It’s not a surprise that the KL-Divergence worked for one case (presumably meaning one combination of features).

Comment: Rest assured, if all goes well, I will cite you. 
Best,

Comment: @DwightDinkins Glad to hear it. If you like the answer, please bump it and accept it. I would be interesting in getting link to thesis. Good luck